# Terraform import failing because Kubernetes provider relies on data sources

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+, terraform-provider-kubernetes

Using Terraform, I'm creating a Kubernetes cluster, installing the [`nginx-ingress-controller`](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/nginx-ingress-controller) Helm chart, and then adding a Route53 hosted zone for my domain (including a wildcard record pointing to the load balancer created by the ingress Helm chart.

To do this I use two separate Terraform files and my process should be as follows -

1. Use Terraform file 1 to `apply` a VPC, EKS cluster and node group.
2. Use the Helm CLI to install the `nginx-ingress-controller` chart (there is an additional requirement not related to this issue that means the Helm chart cannot be installed by Terraform).
3. Import the namespace to which the `nginx-ingress-controller` chart was deployed into the state for Terraform file 2
4. Use Terraform file 2 to `apply` the Route53 hosted zone and record required for ingress.

I thought this was going to work, but the Terraform `import` command has a severe limitation -

> The only limitation Terraform has when reading the configuration files is that the import provider configurations must not depend on non-variable inputs. For example, a provider configuration cannot depend on a data source.

Because I'm using a Kubernetes provider that relies on data sources, I'm falling foul of this limitation.

```
data "aws_eks_cluster" "cluster" {
  name = var.cluster.name
}

data "aws_eks_cluster_auth" "cluster" {
  name = var.cluster.name
}

provider "kubernetes" {
  host                   = data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.endpoint
  cluster_ca_certificate = base64decode(data.aws_eks_cluster.cluster.certificate_authority.0.data)
  token                  = data.aws_eks_cluster_auth.cluster.token
}
```

Taking the following in to account, is there a way of using Terraform that would work?

- I need to output the value of the NS record for the Route53 hosted zone created by the `apply` of Terraform file 2. Because of this, I can't include those resources in Terraform file 1 as the `apply` would fail if an output exists for a module/resource that won't yet exist.
- The namespace must be imported so that it is destroyed when `destroy` is run for Terraform file 2. If it is not, when `destroy` is run for Terraform file 1 it will fail because the VPC won't be able to delete due to the network interface and security group created by the `nginx-ingress-controller` Helm chart.
- The token provided by the `aws_eks_cluster_auth` data source only lasts for 15 minutes (the aws-iam-authenticator cannot provide a longer token), so it is inappropriate to output the token from Terraform file 1 because it's likely to have expired by the time it is used by Terraform file 2.

## Update

I've tried to use an [exec-based credential plugin](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/authentication/#client-go-credential-plugins) as that means no data source would be required, but this causes Terraform to fail right out of the gate. It seems that in this case Terraform tries to create a config file before `module.kubernetes-cluster` has been created, so the cluster doesn't exist.

This provider configuration -

```
provider "kubernetes" {
  host     = module.kubernetes-cluster.endpoint
  insecure = true
  exec {
    api_version = "client.authentication.k8s.io/v1alpha1"
    args        = ["eks", "get-token", "--region", var.cluster.region, "--cluster-name", var.cluster.name]
    command     = "aws"
  }
}
```

Produces this error -

```
╷
│ Error: Provider configuration: cannot load Kubernetes client config
│ 
│   with provider["registry.terraform.io/hashicorp/kubernetes"],
│   on main.tf line 73, in provider "kubernetes":
│   73: provider "kubernetes" {
│ 
│ invalid configuration: default cluster has no server defined
╵
```

Comment: Your provider can't be variable. You can look at terragrunt though. It may be useful in your case.

Comment: Thanks, I'll take a look at Terragrunt.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error when updating my `google_container_cluster` in GKE with a new network configuration. To resolve it, I had to revert to the older network configuration, remove the `provider "kubernetes"`, add the new network configuration and then add `provider "kubernetes"` back.